# Is possible to implement Shared Library Versioning on IBM-AIX?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, aix

I know that shared library versioning can be implemented on Suse Linux. But, is it possible on IBM-AIX?

Any links will be very helpful as I am not able to find proper material through a Google Search.

Answer (score 1):

There are several kinds of library versioning:

- External versioning, e.g. `libreadline.so.4` vs. `libreadline.so.5`
- Internal symbol versioning, as done in `libpthread.so.0` on Linux, which defines e.g. `pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.1` and `pthread_create@GLIBC_2.0`

The latter is a GNU extension, and is not supported on any non-GLIBC system.

The former will work on AIX just fine.

One additional AIX-specific twist is that you can put multiple shared libraries into a single archive library, so your clients can continue to link against e.g. `libfoo.a` (containing `shr.o` and `shr2.o`). Old and already linked clients will continue to use `libfoo.a(shr.o)`, but newly linked clients will use `libfoo.a(shr2.o)`.

That scheme is how AIX manages to support multiple versions of POSIX thread support in a single `libpthread.a`. It is also very confusing for anyone not used to AIX, so you are better off not using it.